# Can I withdraw my vote?

Tags: support, status-completed, votes

I down voted an answer to someone else's question, but then I realized I shouldn't have done so. As it stands right now, I can only take back my "down" vote with an up vote.
Is it just my device? Or is it the system that does not let me withdraw my down vote without leaving an up vote instead

Answer (score 6):

Click the down-vote button again and it will undo it (if you [don't wait too long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80762/241697)).

Comment: I tried (just now) and it seems like it's too late. "Your vote has been locked in.."

Comment: @AlexDoe - Yeah, this is a Stack Exchange "feature" of [some contention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75477/241697).  The only way to change your vote now is if the answer is edited.